# Google Map display in localhost but not in live server

Tags: google-maps

http://www.viethouserestaurant.at/
Please check above the site. Any one can help to solve my issue? 
I have display google map at the last above the footer.
I can see the google map on my localhost but on live server i can not see.

Comment: I recommend inspecting the page and looking at the console for errors when debugging =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running it on a server requires an API key.

A potential issue could be that you didn't declare your website URL in the Google Maps API key page and only included `localhost`. 
Find your API key in the console and add your websites URL

Comment: Thank you tt_Gantz. It's Working for me.